# Resume from suspend taking +70 seconds

Tags: gnome, kernel, suspend, resume

I am experiencing a +70 seconds wait time after opening laptop lid until system actually resume (shows login screen and resume machine). journalctl logs shows this `kernel: PM: resume devices took 72.717 seconds` which is very close to the wait time I'm experiencing.

Is there any fix for his issue?

Comment: You've not provide basic details such as what Ubuntu product, what release of that product, and as kernel maybe involved, if using a LTS release which kernel stack you're using.

Comment: Here's how to get more information. Do: `date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'" >pin.tmp`, then do your shutdown and startup, then `sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"` will show all the logs covering the time period. Examine timestamps, read each line with care.

Comment: What disk do you have, and how much memory? If you have a lot of memory it's not unreasonable for it to take some time.